# MySQL issue with CREATE TABLE

Tags: mysql

I've got this rare issue.. if I use this

```
CREATE TABLE 'my-test-table' (name TEXT, date TEXT)
```

I get a syntax error.. but if I just use ` insead of ' it works

```
CREATE TABLE `my-test-table` (name TEXT, date TEXT)
```

Any clues why? thanks

EDIT:

Oh okay, so the correct sintax for creating tables is using `

```
CREATE TABLE `my-test-table` (name TEXT, date TEXT)
```

And for updating using '

```
UPDATE `my-test-table` SET name = 'MyName'
```

Comment: I vote to close questions where the issue is the distinction between a back tick and single quote in MySQL.  This is a simple typographical error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I did Google it but didn't know how to search for it

Answer (score 1):

The single quotation is used for defining strings. That is why.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an issue. It's just, well, syntax. Only because this symbol ' looks similar to this ` that doesn't mean they are the same token. They are different symbols with different functions.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
CREATE TABLE my-test-table (name TEXT, date TEXT);
```

and table updating

```
  UPDATE my-test-table SET name = 'MyName'  where yourcolum='field what you want';
```